# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'

Tags: vb.net

Hola he estado realizando un asistente de texto que abre programa e interactua, migre este proyecto de visual basic 6.0 a visaul.net framework 5 2019, me ha funcionado todo bien hace lo que pido sin embargo tengo un problema al querer abrir webs, ya que me sale este error System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.'
Y no he logrado tener respuesta[image: Este es el extracto del codigo que abre las webs]

Espero me ayuden muchas gracias

Comment: En lugar de pasar directamente la url a `Process.Start`, intenta pasarle `explorer.exe` como primer parametro, y url como segundo. Algo como `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://www.youtube.com");`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si se resolvio el problema te agradezco qque me hayas dado la solucion